# Combine Polygon and Point Layer

Tags: qgis, combine

Is it possible to combine a point and a polygon layer in one layer from a shapefile in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: no, not with a shapefile  but you can join by attributes if there is a common id.

Comment: Why, what is your next step? You can create a geopackage and place both layers in it, but it will still be two layers

Comment: Do the point geometries absolutely need to physically exist in their own layer, with their own geometry? Could they only need to be graphically displayed? In that case it would be possible to have vertices at their locations on the polygon boundary, and an attribute describing which vertices to draw points on using a rule-based symbology.

Comment: A time ago i got a KML file . It is just ONE file. When i open it in QIS, of course, there are  two layers (point and polygon). But the file in the archive was only one file. how can i save two different layer types in a kml file? Thanks for help :)

Comment: @Christoph Look up Geopackage, like BERA suggested. This database format can include several different layers of different types (points, lines, polygons) into one file.

Comment: GeoPackage can contain both points and polygons also on a single layer but it may not be possible to write such layer with QGIS. Other formats that support the same are for example GeoJSON, GML, OpenJUMP JML, SpatiaLite, and PostGIS. Would you like to know how to combine the layers with ogr2ogr?

Comment: I know gesojson could also store multiple type of geometries. Josm could open it and save it with mutilple type in the same layer. If you watch around geojson or gpx you may find some way to save file of one layer with different type of geometries.

Comment: If you mean two layers in one layer in Layers Panel, No. You cannot combine two layers with different geometry in one layer in GIS software realm like QGIS/ArcGIS unlike CAD softwares like AutoCAD. This is contradictory to the nature of GIS.